# if else - working properly on editor, messed up on android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am new here so have mercy. 
I created a simply method with if else if conditions to check for game objects using an ID and if they are enabled.

I basically have 10 game objects, each of them mirrored by their IDs. so 1 and 6 has id 1, 2 and 7 has id 2 and so on.

This works properly in the editor, but oddly enough, when i try it on a device, im getting weird pairings where in i get 4 and 7 when it should have checked for both 1's.

```
void revealX(){
    int mirror = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < correctButtons.Length; i++) //for loop for all differences
    {   
        if(correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID == 1&&correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled){
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = revealSprite;
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
            mirror++;
            Debug.Log ("rev"+correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID+"mr"+mirror);
            if(mirror ==2){

                return;
            }


        }
        else if (correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID == 2&&correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled){
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = revealSprite;
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
            mirror++;
            Debug.Log ("rev"+correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID+"mr"+mirror);
            if(mirror ==2){
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID == 3&&correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled){
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = revealSprite;
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
            mirror++;
            Debug.Log ("rev"+correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID+"mr"+mirror);
            if(mirror ==2){
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID == 4&&correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled){
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = revealSprite;
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
            mirror++;
            Debug.Log ("rev"+correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID+"mr"+mirror);
            if(mirror ==2){
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID == 5&&correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled){
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite = revealSprite;
            correctButtons[i].GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
            mirror++;
            Debug.Log ("rev"+correctButtons[i].GetComponent<areaID>().ID+"mr"+mirror);
            if(mirror ==2){
                return;
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: How and when are you calling the methods? If it works in the editor then, I can only assume there is a touch event or touch id etc. that is calling the method with wrong implementation.

Comment: How are you setting the `areaID.ID` value?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but, you should really extract that logic out to a method, to follow `DRY`. You've essentially typed out the exact same method 5 times , with a single parameter.